# HTTP to HTTPS working but other way around it is not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

The problem is as following. Only /user should be HTTPS and the rest of the website should be HTTP. I have created two rewrite rules. The second one is working but the first one is not working.

I have search for long time but cannot find the issue:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

#RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd rule may only be working and not the first because you don't have the condition terminated using `$` when it matches just `/user` on the 2nd rule. So if your url's have `/user/morestuff`. The first rule won't work. It will mactch exactly just `/user`. Remove the `$` after user in the first rule and see if it helps you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I've just tested this, doesn't seem to work for me. Navigating to `/user` turns on HTTPS. Then, changing the request URI to `/hello` doesn't revert back to HTTP.

Comment: @MikeRockett I was looking at something else in my previous comment. anyway, Yes these rules do change them back. If the going to /user using https and then changing to /hello, it does change it to http. I'm not sure what you are trying but it works for me. Only his first rule wasn't working.

Comment: (hehe, I had a response typed out there...) That's weird. Perhaps it will only work if I have a certificate in place for the VirtualHost I test with?

Comment: @MikeRockett Yes, def have to have a valid cert. It checks that first before performing rules. You should test your rules here. http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Indeed - I thought that may be the case. Read somewhere that it wouldn't be, but now I know, especially now that I've tested it with a cert.